# How to apply style to a Textview programatically

Tags: android, textbox

I created a textView programatically. Now I need to assign a style to this textview programatically. (Not only the TextAppearance, But also left margins, padding etc.). All of these style attributes are defined in an xml file.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting padding is very easy. But margin is bit triky. Check out below.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
//setting padding left top right bottom
tv.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
//setting left margin
LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
llp.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
tv.setLayoutParams(llp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
   tv.setLayoutParams(params); 
   tv.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
   left- padding to left
   top - padding to right
   right -padding to right
   bottom -padding to bottom
```

For more styling check the link below. See the setter methods. You can set text size, background color and many more.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html.

Answer (score 0):

Use layout params to set this attributes.

```
TextView t = new TextView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(heightInPixels, widthInPixel);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bot);
t.setLayoutParams(params);
mLinearLayout.addView(t);
```

**EDIT:**

If you have own style-able defined in attrs.xml file, then you have to make your own Textview and in constructor handle attributes you want. It's for handling attributes from XML. And for java definition you have to make "set method".

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView
{
   String _stringValue;

    public MyTextView(Context c)
    {
        this(c, null);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(c, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
            super(c, attrs, defStyle);
        TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyStyleAble);
        _stringValue = a.getString(R.styleable.MyStyleAble_stringValue);
        a.recycle(); //don't forget this line! 
    }

    public void setStringValue(String s)
    {
        _stringValue = s;
    } 
}
```

**EDIT**

And here using of MyTextView in code. Just create it by using standard constructor.

```
MyTextView t = new MyTextView(context);
```

Then set your style-able values. In my example it is String value.

```
t.setStringValue("My string text");
```

Then use layoutParams.

```
t.setLayoutParams(params);
```

And add new created TextView to some Layout. For example LinearLayout.

```
mLinearLayout.addView(t);
```

I forgot to say that you have to define style-able int attrs.xml only if you need to set your attributes in XML file.
Then you use it like this.

```
<my.package.name.MyTextView
   xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/my.package.name"
   custom:stringValue="some string text"
   //and also you can use standart android:... attributes
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,


But my problem is i have a style defined in attr.xml


<declare-styleable name="ClassicWidget">
      
        
        <attr name="label1" format="string" />
        <attr name="label1_style" format="reference" />
         
          <attr name="label2" format="string" />
        <attr name="label2_style" format="reference" />
        
        <attr name="limage_src" format="reference" />
        <attr name="rimage_src" format="reference" />
     
     </declare-styleable>


It may include margins , padding and other style items
I have to apply these styles to the textview

Comment: @user1746619 OK. can you post some example. I am not sure if i understand what do you want to do.

Comment: @user1746619 Answer updated. I hope this is what you want to do and that was helpful for you.

Comment: yes, I created a text view using MyTextView class , but how to assign styles to this text view 
public MyTextView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
            super(c, attrs, defStyle);
        TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ClassicWidget);
        _stringValue = a.getString(R.styleable.ClassicWidget_label1_style);
        a.recycle(); //don't forget this line! 
    }
_stringValue has the style, now i need to set this style to the textview.

Answer (score 0):

Use the layoutParams to set the margin for dynamic created textView.

```
TextView view1 = new TextView(this);

view1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(

                       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,

                       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

rlp.setMargins(10,10, 0, 0);
view1.setLayoutParams(rlp);
```

Answer (score 0):

for font style :`textview.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);`

for left margins and padding you need to define "layout params"
like

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(heightInPixels, widthInPixel);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
tv.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
yourLayout.addView(tv);
tv.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
```